# pyFMI parameter estimation and optimization

Tags: python, optimization, modelica

I want to estimate the parameters of my Modelica model by minimizing the error between measured data and my experimental model parameters. The only implementation I found is the Nelder-Mead algorithm optimization and It's not clear how to implement it.

```
 ############################## MODEL #####################################

 from  pyfmi  import  load_fmu
 # Load  model
 model = load_fmu("TrialPython.fmu") ###Model with 13 defined input variables 
 output_fmu=['results.P_DC']### The output variable of the model
 res = model.simulate(input=input_object, ##Simulation
                 start_time = tstart, 
                 final_time = tstop)
 P = res[output_fmu[0]]#### Output of the simulation
 RealP_DC= pd.read_csv(path)### Real data 

 def MSE (parameters):#### OBJECTIVE FUNCTION WE WANT TO MINIMIZE
 return (((SIMULATED(parameters))-RealP_DC)**2).mean())
```

Instead of manually tuning the parameters (13 variables) to minimize the objective function MSE defined like a squared difference between simulated and measured (Real) data how could I implement it with pYFMI. Any hints are welcome

Comment: I am not sure if it's helpful but [scipy.optimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) has a bunch of optimization methods available.

Comment: This is true just to pyFMI implementation is not clear

Comment: You may be able to minimize your objective function using `scipy` instead.

Comment: The question is how to put the pyFMU output in the form suitable for optuimization

Comment: [Section 4.4](http://portal.research.lu.se/portal/files/7201641/pyfmi_tech.pdf) may be helpful

Comment: You could get inspired by https://github.com/sdu-cfei/modest-py or use this tool for your task (based on pyfmi and scipy)

Comment: @ChristianBertsch Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you